# How do I give only the owner of a folder write/delete access?

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod, read-only

How can I create a folder that:

- everybody has read access to the contents of the folder
- only the owner has write/delete access to the contents

Comment: This is the default behavior when you create a folder with a user, it's writable by the user, but readable by everybody.

Comment: 1. Impossible. "root" and the"sudo" user can ALWAYS delete a folder.  2. Physical access to the machine means someone can use a live session and delete a directory. Even when not the owner.

Comment: _"allows write/delete access only if you're the owner of it"_ -- the owner of __what__? Owner of the directory or the owner of the contents within it?

Answer (score 7):

Create a folder and run `chmod` (change file mode) to change the permissions.

```
mkdir folder
chmod 755 folder
```

actually this is the default.

Changing permissions of the content of an already existing folder:

```
# Give write access to owner
chmod -R u+w folder
# Revoke write access of group and others
chmod -R go-w folder
# Give read access to everyone
chmod -R a+r folder
```

Or together in one command (thx @chrylis)

```
chmod -R u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx folder
```

Comment: The compound form `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx` is a bit simpler.

Comment: @chrylis Didn't know the one-line form existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Give the owner user all permissions and everybody else only read and execute, and take away write permissions for everything inside:

```
sudo setfacl -Rm u::rwX,g::rX,o::rX /path/to/directory
sudo setfacl -Rdm u::rwX,g::rX,o::rX /path/to/directory
```

The first sets the permissions for existing things, and the second sets the default permissions for anything created in the directory. `rwX` grants all permissions (X grants execute if a directory or if already executable).

Comment: Why do this and not `chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`?

Comment: @chrylis "the second sets the default permissions for anything created in the directory."

Comment: Unless you're saying chmod also magically does that.

Comment: `chmod` controls who's allowed to make changes *to the directory*. You can't delete files from a directory, even if you own them, without write access.

Comment: @chrylis the question also talks about write access to the files. Not just delete. You can write to a file without write access to the directory.

Comment: It's ambiguous, and I interpreted it differently.

Answer (score 4):

The permission bits (in *octal*) you need:

```
0705
```

Or if you want to grant read/access permission to the group too (this makes sense given you are giving read/execute to the world):

```
0755
```

The `0` in front indicates the absence of any SUID, SGID, or Sticky bit. You can drop that if you want.

In descriptive letter form:

```
rwxr-xr-x
```